# Javascript Clonenode() - get element by id?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, clonenode

I am fiddling with this javascript code here

http://jsfiddle.net/7Sd4W/4/

I am trying to get it to clone a select element with ID = "sel0"

Then when It clones it I want it to create the same select element but with "sel+i" , i increments meaning everytime its cloned

The ids would be sel0,sel1,sel2,sel3,sel4 etc..

I tried changing

> document.getelementsbyID()

or

> document.getelementsbyname()

However it does not seem to work

Thanks

Comment: it's getElementById not getElementsById and it's case sensitive

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working ?

Comment: It does: http://jsfiddle.net/7Sd4W/10/. `getElementById` returns one element with that ID. There should only be one anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` works. You can also assign a unique ID to the node before appending it (duplicate IDs can cause all kinds of issues):

See http://jsfiddle.net/7Sd4W/9/

Answer (score 2):

```
var copy = orig.cloneNode(true);
copy.setAttribute("id", modify(orig.getAttribute("id")));
document.body.appendChild(el)
```

Comment: What is the `modify()` method on line 2?  Is it standard javascript?  What does it do?  Where is it defined?

Comment: modify - is something where you somehow change current id. the simplest is, say, increment. it is just any function that guarantee to change input.